# Problem with RDLC: Applying font color expression in multiple report only one report is working fine

Tags: .net-core, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I'm encountering an issue with RDLC where I'm applying a font color expression to multiple reports, but it's only working as expected in one report. In the other reports, the condition is not having the desired impact.

solution is there any alternate method

Comment: Show what you've tried. If you haven't made an effort, do so and add it to your question,